# How to print a .prn(uploaded) file using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a project where i need to upload a .prn file from user and need to print the file to the zebra printer using angular.js.

However I have tried searching it on net and have found no answer.

Can someone please let me know if there is any solution for this.